# For what positive value $c$ does the equation $x^x = c \ln(x)$ have exactly one solution?

Tags: calculus

For what positive value $c$ does the equation $x^x = c \ln(x)$ have exactly one solution?

For a positive number $c$, if $x^x = c \ln(x)$ has exactly one solution, then there exists a unique point $k$ such that both of the curves $f(x) = x^x$ and $g(x) = c \ln(x)$ intersect. This implies that both curves have a common tangent line at $k$ and so we can equate derivatives to get $$x^x (\ln(x) + 1) = \frac{c}{x}.$$ Therefore, we have the system of equations
\begin{align*}
x^x &= c \ln(x) \\
x^x (\ln(x) + 1) &= \frac{c}{x}.
\end{align*}
I am having trouble solving this system of equations. Maybe this is not the way to approach the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If any two curves intersect, they need not to have common tangent at that point.

Comment: A specific counter example as per Jaideep's comment is $e^x$ and $y=2$ intersect at exactly one point: $(\ln(2), 2)$ but have derivative $2$ and $0$ respectively at that point.

Comment: Numerical experimentation shows that the answer is near $c=4.5$ and $x=1.55$ but I don't have an explanation for why that is the answer.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I drew some graphs and I am quite sure that in this case, the two curves will be tangent for exactly one solution.

Comment: I applied condition for tangency and got the solution on W|A to be $x \approx 1.55913$, $c \approx 4.50008$

Comment: Yea, I am just getting confused on how to actually prove that there is exactly one solution

Comment: That when the two curves have exactly one intersection, they are tangent there, is due to $x^x$ being convex on $[1,\infty)$ and $\ln(x)$ being concave. (No intersections are possible when $x < 1$ since $\ln(x) < 0$ there.)