# Solving System of equations: $x^x = c \ln(x)$; $x^x (\ln(x) + 1) = \frac{c}{x}$

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

I have been trying to solve this system of equations for a few days now and I can't seem to figure it out. The equations are:
\begin{align*}
 x^x &= c \ln(x) \\
x^x (\ln(x) + 1) &= \frac{c}{x},
\end{align*}
where $c$ is a positive real number. Any suggestions? Using W|A, $x \approx 1.5591332$ and $c \approx 4.5000827.$

Comment: Notice that the second equation is just the derivative of the first equation with respect to $x$.

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but it what way does that help?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps. I haven't come up with anything helpful from it. Just thought I'd make you aware. Not a dumb question!

Comment: Ok, thanks! I was a little worried that based on what you said, the solution was obvious. = )

Comment: For those who don't know the original question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231290/for-what-positive-value-c-does-the-equation-xx-c-lnx-have-exactly-one By the OP, I too didn't get any solution @ATLKing, hope this one gets one.

Comment: Thanks for linking the OP. I did not know how to do that!

Comment: Granted the two equations are satisfied when the first one has one solution, I get this equation $$y^2+y=e^{-y}$$ It doesn't seems difficult to prove it confirms the uniqueness point.

Comment: Did you set $y = \ln(x)$? So basically, we have $$(\ln(x))^2 + \ln(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: Yes. Anyway, you have the solution with pretty good approximation...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution but several observations (and too long for a comment)

Substituting $c=x^{x+1}(ln(x)+1)$ into the first equation gives $$
x^x=x^{x+1}(ln(x)+1)ln(x) \tag{1}$$$$
0=x(ln(x)+1)ln(x)-1$$
Let $f(x)= \frac{x^x}{cln(x)}$ then $$
f^\prime(x) = \frac{x^{x-1}}{ln^2(x)}(x(ln(x)+1)ln(x)-1)$$

So the solution for $x$ in the simultaneous equations is the same value that makes the derivative $0$ (because $x^{x-1}$ can never be zero).

This makes sense when you consider that $c$ is defined such the $x^x > cln(x)$ for all $x$ except one point where they are equal. Therefore that one point must be the minimum of $f(x)$.

So, whether you solve for the derivative being zero, or whether you make the substitution as in (1), you end up needing to solve $$0=xln^2(x)+xln(x)-1 \tag{2}$$

I don't believe this solvable with with algebraic techniques. I also don't believe it is solvable using the Lambert W function.

However, substituting $x=e^z$ gives $e^{-z}=z(z+1)$. This is in the form of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) which the linked to article discusses.